# How to access browser version in class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm writing a vb.net svg workflow viewer, but need to do browser detection to see if I should revert to VML or if SVG is supported. Our targeted browser is IE, and I know that to detect browser version in VB you can do the following:

```
Dim myBrowserCaps As System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities = Request.Browser
If (CType(myBrowserCaps, System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase)).Browser.ToUpper().IndexOf("IE") >= 0 Then
    labelText = "Browser is Internet Explorer."
Else
    labelText = "Browser is not Internet Explorer."
End If
```

Or something similiar.

The problem is, that while I can detect the browser and UserAgent string directly from my .aspx page, when I put the same code into a class that is referenced by a webpart on the page (yes webpart, it's a legacy product) I get an error. The webpart is referenced by many pages, which is why I want the browser detection in the class instead of on the page.

```
Dim Browser As HttpBrowserCapabilities = Request.Browser
If Browser.Browser = "IE" Then
    'IE Junk
End If
```

The error is simply `"'Request' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level".`

This code is copied directly from the MSDN documentation and for the life of me I can't find anywhere that explains how or if I can do this from a class. I've browser Stack, I've also browsed their documentation to no avail.

I've already tried `HttpRequest.Browser` instead, but this got me no where.

So, my two questions are...

- What am I doing wrong?
- What am I missing about accessing the request object, because I'm obviously missing something?

**Edit**

Originally I had tried using the current context, but I had done it incorrectly.
I had tried:

```
Dim browser as HttpBrowserCapabilities = HttpContext.Request.Browser
```

When it should have been:

```
Dim browser as HttpBrowserCapabilities = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser
```

So I was wrong syntactically (and in understanding)

I think the question would probably still be helpful, as I couldn't find it reproduced anywhere else.

Thanks to all!

Comment: You need to pass the `HttpContext`.

Comment: Tried that as well, obviously I wasn't doing it correctly.

Comment: Just edited with my attempts. And your comment made my think an original attempt was probably the right track... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per SLaks comment, the HttpContext must be passed in to access the browser from the request. I ended up using.

```
 Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
 Dim Browser As HttpBrowserCapabilities = context.Request.Browser
```